# Why does the object synchronize(reactive) outside component whereas the single variable does not?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vue-component

To demonstrate this issue, I've created the same behavior via JSFiddle.

Check this out https://jsfiddle.net/sarapmax/xy5qg6bo/21/

As you can see, when I click the `submit` button, it emits the values out to the parent component.

Then, I declared the empty `parentBudget` object in the parent component and set it equal to the emitted values.

---

The thing is when I click the `submit` button and type on those v-model inputs in the child, they are syncing with the parent. But `this.foo` which is not outside `this.budget` object is not syncing with the parent.

My question is why? Ideally, I don't want the parent synching with the child every time I type, it should perform only when I press the `submit` button.

Comment: Because it's the same object. When you do `{foo: this.foo, budget: this.budget}` you didn't create the new object you just create a new reference and that reference points to `budget` which reactive. For foo, it behave different since it's a string not an object.

Comment: @User28 How to make the object in the parent not reactive? I tried `Object.assign()`. It didn't work.

Comment: I found a solution using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())`